# String format with NumberFormat

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm formatting a String that i enter in a JTextField using NumberFormat instance without specifying the location.  As a result i have a String that represents a number formatted with white spaces as separator.  I have a problem to get rid of the white spaces when i want to use the String for other processes.  I have tried `string.replaceAll(" ", "");` and `string.replaceAll("\\s", "");` but none of it works.

```
String string = ((JTextField)c).getText();
string = string.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Also when i do `int index = string.indexOf(" ");` or `int index = string.indexOf("\\s");` it returns -1, which means that it doesn't find the character.
When i do

```
for(Character ch : string.toCharArray()) {
System.out.println("ch : " + ch.isSpaceChar(ch))
}
```

it returns true for the empty char.  How is represented a space char in java ?

I tried also

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(((JTextField)c).getText());
String string = b.toString.replaceAll("\\s", "");
System.out.println("string : " + string);
```

It doesn't replace a thing.

Comment: please post a small working section of your code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Are you setting the original string to the return value of the replaceAll functions you are calling? Are you then updating whatever is consuming that value with the new value from your replaceAll function?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `string = string.replaceAll(" ", "");`? - string is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "89774lf&933 k880990";

string = string.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );

System.out.println(string);
```

OUTPUT:

```
89774933880990
```

It will eliminate all the `char` other than `digits`.

Comment: updated in the code try the other one and check it is working.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but i would like to understand why the replaceAll method doesn't work and then fix it, and not doing a parser myself.

Comment: well dont use this code.. just try if you get exception in this way, possibly there may be some other char than space

Comment: It works and i don't have a NumberFormatException.  But i cannot use this method.

Comment: You are only replacing space and its not working but this code is working that means there is(are) some chars other than space. So try comparing the output.

Comment: I don't see how can i find which character it is.  There are load of chars other than digit.